# Only Plotting Strings with a Frequency Greater Than 2

Tags: python, pandas, plot

In the following code, I want pd.plot() to ignore all cases that occur 1 time. i.e., only plot the strings that are in the list more than once. How would I go about doing that?

Here's some example code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'e']
pd.Series(x).value_counts().plot('barh')
plt.show()
```

In other words, 'b' and 'd' occur one time each. How do I remove these data points from the plot *before* plotting, i.e., without just using `xlim = [2,4]`. I'm trying to use something similar with my financial data. I'm reading a csv file with a ton of rows, so I'd like to remove all single instances of a string before plotting it. Please let me know if I need to clarify.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
s = pd.Series(x).value_counts()
s[s > 1].plot('barh')
```

Or [selection by callable](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) if want one line solution:

```
pd.Series(x).value_counts().loc[lambda x: x > 1].plot('barh')
```